Suggestions to create a professional 2024 Email signature
I have a graphic design request to create a business email signature template with cta line, logo, social links for various clients/employees for a small company. I need help to create this signature so it is properly selectable and editable and can be placed in Microsoft Outlook and won’t break when sent out? What should be used as a way to approach this? I have checked out this website: https://create.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/email-signatures ; also learned on the Microsoft Outlook forum that there could be a bug copy pasting this grid from Microsoft Word into the microsoft outlook signature builder (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/email-signature-formatting-wont-copy-over-into-the/2a570d6f-7113-47b0-8f7f-161614b8849f). What could be some solutions? or workarounds?

"there could be a bug copy pasting this grid" Why don't you test it to find out what "bug" you find, before finding a workaround? And then solve the specific bug?

My pet peeve: One needs to differentiate between sales emails and communication emails. A "professional" email signature for communication emails should be nothing more than text. Don't clutter communications with pointless, arrogant, images. The mark of a "small company" is that they don't understand the difference.

Design it in Outlook. That way you can know it will work correctly in the platform that the client cares the most about.
